# Scraping multiple div classes with the same name using Beautiful Soup in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have succesfully scraped the image and title of a webpage (URL in code). I want to do this for all movies that are on this page. 'movie_list' contains all of this, but only the first movie information is scraped.

I tried changing `.find` to `.find_all` but this gives me an error.

```py
url = 'https://5movies.to/movie/'
content = session.get(url, verify=False).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
movie_list = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'movie-list'})
all_item = []

for allContainers in movie_list:
    filmName = allContainers.find('img').get('alt')
    filmFoto = allContainers.find('img').get('src')
    filmLink = allContainers.find('a').get('href')
print(filmName)
```

Comment: use `find_all()` instead of `find()`. and `for`-loop to get `src` from every element.  If you get error then show it in question. Always show full error message in question.

Comment: you have to put `print()` inside `for`-loop to display all `filmName`. OR put values `filmName` on some list - ie `all_item.append(filmName)` - and later display all elements from this list. Variable `filmName` can keep only one (last) value.

Comment: Can you post a working example so we can try it?

Comment: _I tried changing .find to .find_all but this gives me an error._ Please share the entire error message, and a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the print statement inside of the `for` loop made it print out the whole list.
Indeed I replaced the `print` with `all_item.append((filmName, filmFoto, filmLink))` to send it to my frontend.

Acknowledgements to @furas for the information!

```py
url = 'https://5movies.to/movie/'
content = session.get(url, verify=False).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
movie_list = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'movie-list'})
all_item = []

for allContainers in movie_list:
    filmName = allContainers.find('img').get('alt')
    filmFoto = allContainers.find('img').get('src')
    filmLink = allContainers.find('a').get('href')
    print(filmName)
```